# How to redirect user to login before he can add products to cart and disable AJAX Cart - NopCommerce

Tags: nopcommerce

I am using NopCommerce version 3.0. I want the users to get redirected to the login page before they can add products to the cart. I also want to disable the AJAXCart (I want full postback and the products to get added to the cart.).

Please guide me as to how to achieve it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something similar here: http://clinidirect.co.uk/c-20/continence-care if you add an item to the bag, a popup appears, if you click on "Go to bag" it asks you to login.

This is very rough, but should give you an idea:

First, in `_ProductVariantAddToCart.cshtml` remove the onclick javascript event from the button, so that the button actually posts the form to `AddProductVariantToCart` in `CatalogController`. This should remove the AjaxCart.

This will also add the item to the cart and redirect you to the shoppingcart page.

When the ShoppingCart page loads in action `Cart`. Add the following:

```
if(_workContext.CurrentCustomer.IsGuest())
    return new HttpUnauthorizedResult("Cart requires the user to have an account");
```

This will send the user to the login page giving the impression that the user needs to login to add items to the cart.

Hope this helps

Comment: I will try this and let you know. Thanks for your reply :)